# What is the precise definition of infinite limit at infinity of a function?

Tags: limits, analysis, functions, definition, infinity

I saw the following definition on youtube.

Let $f$ be a function defined on some interval $(a, +\infty)$

$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x)= +\infty$ (1)

means $\forall N > 0$ $\exists M > 0$ such that $x > M$ implies $f(x) > N$.

Is this a correct and general definition for equation (1)? For example, the function $f$ defined below doesn't satisfy the above definition, but it is obviously divergent, as $x \to +\infty$.

$f(x) \equiv \log(x) \sin^2(x)$, $x \in (0, +\infty)$

Comment: Yes, that is the definition. The example $f$ that you gave doesn't have a limit that is $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try to understand this. So the divergence of a function doesn't necessarily mean it asymptotically approaches the infinity, as $x \to +\infty$, correct?

Comment: Or, in another word, the equation (1) is not the definition of the divergence of a function, as $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: That’s correct. Although if someone writes not just “is divergent”, but “diverges to positive infinity”, they would mean equation (1).

Comment: Yes, a limit that is $+\infty$ is a special case of those called "divergent" in calculus. It is closer in properties to limits that exist, that are called "convergent" than to other divergent limits.

Comment: To avoid confusion, it would be better to write “is not convergent” instead of “is divergent”.

Comment: One (uncommon) term for nonconvergent functions which don’t diverge to either positive or negative infinity is oscillatory.

Comment: To add to the above answers, the limit being infinity, in English, is like "$f(x)$ will be greater than $N$, as long as $x$ is large enough."

In your example where you have the oscillating function, it doesn't satisfy the above definition because sometimes when you have large $x$, $f(x)$ is still small (or negative), so it's never possible for $x$ to be "large enough," since the function will always come back down